# Typescript Interface objects property value as key

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-typings

i try to create correct typings for situations, when trying to map the array of objects to array with the same objects but using the property value as index key..

[Code on playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%0D%0Ainterface%20ValueDefinition%20%7B%0D%0A%09name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20x%3A%20ValueDefinition%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%09name%3A%20'supers'%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getByName%3CV%20extends%20ValueDefinition%3E(valuDefinition%3A%20V)%7B%0D%0A%09let%20out%20%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0D%0A%09out%5BvaluDefinition.name%5D%20%3D%20valuDefinition%3B%0D%0A%09return%20out%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20key%20%3D%20getByName(x)%3B%0D%0Akey.supers%3B%0D%0A)

```
interface ValueDefinition {
    name: string;
}

function getByName<V extends ValueDefinition>(valuDefinitions: V[]) {
    let out  = {}

    for (const key in valuDefinitions) {
        out[valuDefinitions[key].name] = valuDefinitions[key];
    }
    return out;
}

const obj: ValueDefinition = {
    name: 'super'
};


const objKey = getByName([
    obj
]);

key.super; // Typings for this output
```

I looking for something like this:

```
type WithKey<D extends ValueDefinition> = {
    [key: D['name']]: D;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are the names known at compile time?

Comment: Yes the are known.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make your `ValueDefinition` interface generic in the string literal type of the `name` property, so you can extract it later:

```
interface ValueDefinition<K extends string = string> {
    name: K
}
```

Then you can represent the output of your `getByName()` function as the following mapped type:

```
type ValueDefinitionObject<K extends string> = {[P in K]: ValueDefinition<P>}
```

And revise the signature of `getByName` to be generic in the set of `name` literals:

```
function getByName<K extends string>(valuDefinitions: Array<ValueDefinition<K>>): ValueDefinitionObject<K> {
    let out = {} as ValueDefinitionObject<K>
    for (const key in valuDefinitions) {
        out[valuDefinitions[key].name] = valuDefinitions[key];
    }
    return out;
}
```

At this point it will work, but you have to be careful to declare your `obj` so that the type of the value `'super'` is inferred as `'super'` and not `string`.  This identity function will help:

```
function asValueDefinition<K extends string>(vd: ValueDefinition<K>): ValueDefinition<K> {
    return vd;
}
```

Okay, let's try it (with another one I'm adding):

```
const obj = asValueDefinition({ name: 'super' });
const obj2 = asValueDefinition({ name: 'thing' });
```

If you inspect them they show up as `ValueDefinition<'super'>` and `ValueDefinition<'thing'>`.

```
const objKey = getByName([obj, obj2]);
```

And `objKey` is typed as `ValueDefinitionObject<'super'|'thing'>`.  Let's use it:

```
objKey.super; // okay, ValueDefinition<'super'>
objKey.thing; // okay, ValueDefinition<'thing'>
objKey.nope; // error, property 'nope' doesn't exist
```

Does that work for you?  Good luck!

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Uh oh, sorry!

Comment: It's fine, it was fair and square :)